# Forwarding localhost to ipv4

Tags: localhost, ipv4, ip-forward

I'm trying to forward my octant running on 127.0.0.1:7777 to ipv4 .

I have already gone to /etc/hosts/ and change the localhost to 192.168...
but not working
What else must I do to forward it to my ipv4 too become accessible through the network ?

My system is an ubuntu

Comment: you should set the environment variable `OCTANT_LISTENER_ADDR=0.0.0.0:80` before starting octant. maybe you need to use a port higher than 1024. I did not test it.

Comment: @dummyuser It’s probably not that environment variable…but rather `OCTANT_ACCEPTED_HOSTS`

Comment: Try setting that variable when starting octant e.g. `OCTANT_ACCEPTED_HOSTS=“0.0.0.0” octant`

Comment: and does this setting work ? no. I wrote `OCTANT_LISTENER_ADDR` and I ment  `OCTANT_LISTENER_ADDR`.  `OCTANT_ACCEPTED_HOSTS ` may be added later. The format  `0.0.0.0` is not valid. It should be  `0.0.0.0/0 `, this is the default and not needed.

Comment: @dummyuser My bad :-) I am writing from my phone and barely see only a part  of the comment box and obviously missed the subnet mask part  … thanks for the correction … I doubt it’s the default though.